# Data transfer measurement between databases

Tags: database, ms-access

I'd like to measure how many data (in MB) were transfered between 2 Access databases during specific operations.
On of the databases is on local disk, the other is in network. I'd like to work out design solution which will minimalise data transfer during specific operations (like data loading, appending data, checking data quality) having all needed data in 'mother' db. E.g. where to put data marts and how to synchronise them. Possibility of measurement data transfer in different scenarios will help me out in finding the best design solution having max performance.

Is there some tool which provide this possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access doesn't really include built-in instrumentation for the information you want.  Look into the [ISAMStats Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa188211%28v=office.10%29.aspx#odc_4009c15_topic4) to see whether you can use the information it gives you as a reasonable approximation.

That sample chapter contains a wealth of other information regarding application optimization.  So, since your goal is to maximise performance, you may find it useful even if ISAMStats is not.

Comment: +1 for the tip on ISAMStats. (I knew about ShowPlan, but ISAMStats was news to me.)

Comment: Thanks! ISAMStats sounds promising. DAO/ADO optimizations will be also helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) would be able to capture the information you need. As described in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark):

> Wireshark is a free and open-source packet analyzer. It is used for network troubleshooting, analysis, software and communications protocol development, and education.

I have used Wireshark (and its predecessor, Ethereal) for many years. It's one of those tools that I don't need to use often, but it can be a godsend when I *do* need to use it.

Comment: WireShark sounds interesting here.  Wouldn't he need to move that one db from local disk to a network share for the shark to pick up activity?

Comment: Not as I understand the question. Traffic "between the databases" will go over the wire if one of the databases is local and the other one is on a network share. Wireshark will capture that traffic (inbound and outbound) and once captured it can be filtered, summarized, etc..

Comment: Right, between the databases.  Sorry then.  Doh!

Comment: Thank You. Wireshark is a great tool.